# Python cant recognize the if - Statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, input

I'm very new in Coding and I started with Python to understand how to code.
I'm going to program a simple quiz, where the User choose which Quiz they want to play.
I did it the input() and yet it does not go to the if - Statement.
Code:

```
import quiz1
import quiz2
import quiz3
import quiz4

quiz = input("Please choose which Quiz you want to play (1-4): ")
print(quiz)

if quiz == 1:
        quiz1
        #f1 = open(fragebogen1.py)
        #print(f1)
elif quiz == 2:
        print("hello")
elif quiz == 3:
        print("hello")
elif quiz == 4:
        print("hello")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `input()`  returns a string. You are comparing that string against an integer and that check can never be `True`. check for `if quiz == '1'`.

Answer (score 3):

The `input` function returns a string. You need to convert the user's input to integer:

```
quiz = int(input("Please choose which Quiz you want to play (1-4): "))
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert input to integer before checking

```
if int(quiz) == 1:
```

Comment: checking against a string is better. `int(quiz)` can raise an Error,  `if quiz == '1':` cannot + you do not actually need an integer here; no math is done.

Comment: May I know why ?

Comment: If you are going to wrap the input, you should probably do it as the input is received (i.e. `quiz = int(input("..."))`) otherwise you'll need to do it for each `elif`

Comment: i tested both, but the didnt solve the problem i want to say python " Hey open the other file "quiz1" and read it" After i wrote a number from 1 - 4 it just write it down and stops

Answer (score -1):

The `elif == 1` cannot be reached, since you put in an `if quiz == 1` above.
Instead you need to put in `elif quiz == 2:`.

Comment: while this is true, this does not solve the question OP asked so this should be a comment instead

Comment: That's in fact true, but I cannot comment yet, therefore I added it down here.